# Using group and backreference in regex in R - stringr::str_replace

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a simple situation, but I'm struggling to use **group** and **backreference** in regex. How could I do that with `stringr::str_replace` ?.

For example, I want to transform `test.txt` in `test.evaluation.txt`. I'm wishing something like this:

```
stringr::str_replace("test.txt", "\\.(\\1)$", ".evaluation.(\\1)")
```

I'd like to use the group "1" to save the file format. Thanks in advance if someone can help with an answer in this format.

Comment: I think the pattern match should be differnt

Comment: `stringr::str_replace("test.txt", "\\.([^.]*)$", ".evaluation.\\1")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**
With `stringr`:

```
stringr::str_replace_all(my_string,"([a-z])(.txt)","\\1.evaluation\\2")
[1] "test.evaluation.txt"
```

Not the most efficient:

```
my_string<-"test.txt"
res<-unlist(strsplit(my_string,"\\."))
paste0(res[1],".evaluation.",res[2])
[1] "test.evaluation.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `sub` to match a `.` and replace it with `.` followed by 'evaluation' and another `.`

```
sub("\\.", ".evaluation.", my_string)
#[1] "test.evaluation.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

With capturing groups:

```
sub("\\.([[:alnum:]]+)$","\\.evaluation\\.\\1","text.txt")
[1] "text.evaluation.txt"
```